# How do I pass a URL querystring in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass a querystring value when I open a view. I have set up my router like this:

```
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Summary from "../views/Summary.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/summary/:id",
    name: "Summary",
    component: Summary
  }
];
```

The home.vue has this link:

```
<a href="#" class="card-link" @click.prevent="goSummary(item.id)">View Item Summary</a> <!--item.id came from the v-for loop-->
```

The home.vue has this on the export default script

```
methods: {
  goSummary(id) {
    //do other things here
    this.$router.replace('Summary/'+id); //I'm supposed to see the view
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Summary', params: { id: item.id } }">
  View
</router-link>
```

or via javascript:

```
  this.$router.push({ name: 'Summary', params: { id: this.item.id } })
```

For further information, see [vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link)